# Scroll in GVim using touch screen device

Tags: vim, touch, windows-8.1

I'm using GVim on a Surface Pro 3 that has a touch screen. I've gotten so used to scrolling windows (like the browser) using the touch screen, so I thought it would be nice to be able to do the same in GVim. However, when I drag my finger it selects text rather than scrolling. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whohooo, my first tumbleweed badge. :-) Anyway, this actually works out of-the-box with the Vim build from https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows

Comment: That link is dead. Do you have a newer link?

Comment: Mostly built in... I'm using SPF13 vim and it's O.K...

Looks like if you touchswipe left/right you select text, and if you touchswipe up/down you scroll one of your window buffers... maybe not the one you expect though. Hopefully there will be some movement here, because I do like to stay in one mode of interaction for a second sometimes. I don't necessarily want to have to jk after a touch testing session. 

Good question... guess it's still not a popular use case? mrow.